# PHP Array JSON to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

in php

```
<?php
    $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
    echo json_encode($arr); // {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
?>
```

in javascript,

```
$.getJSON('drivetracker2.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I am trying to access the php array which was sent via json to javascript.
but it says data is undefined.
anyone know why and how to fix this problem?

Comment: What the result is if you access `drivetracker2.php` in browser?

Comment: The code you posted looks good to me. Are you trying to access `data` anywhere else?

Comment: If you're using a modern browser such as Chrome/Firefox, you should be inspecting the request with your development tools. This will allow you to determine whether the request is sending/receiving correctly.

Comment: @pktangyue it does not output anything on drivetracker2.php

Comment: @felix no it does not. console.log(data) in javascript

Comment: @juco yes the request was received correctly on chrome

Comment: @ealeon so you need check why it output nothing.

Comment: why would <?php
    $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
    echo json_encode($arr); // {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
?> output nothing on drivetracker2.php??

Comment: Are you trying to use data OUTSIDE the '.getJSON' function?

Comment: @inversivemedia well, i have it stored var drives = data. and im trying to output drives. are there ways to save data?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question: [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $.post('drivetracker2.php', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 },'json');
```

Comment: Why should this make a difference? Please explain.

Comment: You need to specify in what format the response is going to be sent. Here he is saying Jquery that "the response I'm waiting for, is a JSON string", so it will be parsed to a JSON object automatically

Comment: @Loupax: Was this directed at me? `$.getJSON` also tells jQuery to treat the response as JSON. There is no difference to the OP's code, only that it is POST instead of GET.

Comment: I didn't see the `$.getJSON` part. In that case there is indeed no difference other than the type of the HTTP request :/

Answer (score 1):

Add this just before you echo the json.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```